Is there a representation-agnostic way to show that the dynamical vibronic couplings diverge for degenerate potential energy surfaces?
To describe a molecular system beyond the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, the derivation of the vibronic couplings between adiabatic electronic states leads to the conclusion that couplings through the kinetic energy diverge when the potential energy surfaces (PES) become degenerate. To get to that point, one usually needs to work the kinetic energy operator in the position representation so that the gradients with respect to the nuclear coordinates become explicit. In fact, it is in the so-called derivative coupling term where divergences appear.
However, one can also derive that the matrix elements of the nuclear momentum operator diverge under the same conditions if expressed in terms of its commutator with the electronic Hamiltonian.
Is it possible, then, to derive an expression that shows the problematic nature of degenerate PES without resorting to the position representation? To be specific, I'm looking for a representation-free or representation-agnostic derivation.

How do you expect to calculate something without a representation?

What I'm looking for is a way to write things in terms of the momentum and position operators without necessarily expressing them as differential operators or constants.
